# Jekyll iterate over a triple dimension array

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Using Jekyll 3.3 I create an array into the `_config.yml` file :

```
profiles:
  - user1: 
    - username: "test"
    - link: "http://test.test"
```

I want to get the value `username` and `link` for each user. So I use a double loop :

```
{% for profile in site.profiles %}
    {% for user in profile %}
        {{ user.username }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that doesn't print anything, Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With datas arranged like this :

```
profiles:
  - username: "test"
    link: "http://test.test"
  - username: "test2"
    link: "http://test.test2"
```

You can do :

```
{% for user in site.profiles %}
  <a href="{{ user.link }}">{{ user.username }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```